# Why do these two have different shading?

Tags: modeling

This is weird. Why do these two have different shading, despite having very similar geometry? I thought the problem was the shading mode (one is smooth, one is flat), but when I enable shading smooth on the left shape, its shading remains unchanged. So, what's the problem?

[image: Left shape topology]
[image: Right shape topology]

Here's my [Blend File](https://filebin.net/k2jf7caxp4g03sim).

Comment: could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @moonboots: Hi, I've updated with the blend file. Sometimes I can produce the left shape, sometimes I can't. I dont get why.

Comment: could you please use another download platform, this one doesn't seem to work...

Comment: Hi, I've re-updated the link. Sorry for the inconvenience and thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of your object is auto-smoothed, the other is not. You have smoothed both your objects in the *Tools* panel > *Tools* > *Edit* > *Shading* > *Smooth*. Blender can't smooth a very angular and low-poly mesh without apparent artefacts. With *Auto Smooth* it will only smooth below the chosen angle and therefore you will avoid these kind of artefacts for the superior values.

[image]

Comment: Omg. Thank a ton for this, moonboots. It causes me a lot of frustration, becasue sometimes I can produce the same result as the left but have no idea why.